# local development with secrets

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I am following this guide to get secrets added to my prod environment with cloudflare workers:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables/#comparing-secrets-and-environment-variables

I am able to add new secrets via `wrangler secret put`, and I see them in the dashboard.  When I run my code locally with wrangler, it doesn't look like the variables are injected.  I'm getting an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: TOKEN is not defined
  at line 0

    at throwFetchError (/Users/justin.beckwith/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:134316:17)
    at fetchResult (/Users/justin.beckwith/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:134287:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async previewToken (/Users/justin.beckwith/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:134658:29)
    at async createWorker (/Users/justin.beckwith/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:134675:17)
    at async start (/Users/justin.beckwith/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:136075:16) {
```

I know the secret is set, and from what I can tell the values should be auto-injected.  Any ideas on what I'm missing here?  Thank you!

Comment: Did you find out how to make this work by any chance? Both answers provided work for normal environment variables defined in `wrangler.toml`, but it does not automatically inject the secrets I put via `wrangler secret put`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler2/issues/190). You can create the file named `.dev.vars`, and put the secrets in file. Wrangler 2 will auto binding when you use the command `$ wrangler dev`

**example:**

1. put the secret in `.dev.vars` files

```bash
API_KEY_0 = "YOU_SECRET_0"
API_KEY_1 = "YOU_SECRET_1"
```

2. run the command below and you can see this in terminal.

```bash
$ wrangler dev

...

Your worker has access to the following bindings:
- Vars:
  - API_KEY_0: "(hidden)"
  - API_KEY_1: "(hidden)"

...
```

3. you code in `.ts` or `.js`

```js
interface Env {
  API_KEY_0: string
  API_KEY_1: string
}

export default {
  async fetch(request: Request, env: Env, context: ExecutionContext): Promise<Response> {
    console.log(env.API_KEY_0, env.API_KEY_1)
  }
}
```

```js
export default {
  async fetch(request, env, context) {
    console.log(env.API_KEY_0, env.API_KEY_1)
  }
}
```

for your reference

Comment: So the secrets only work when we deployed them only?

if we want it to inject to normal env context we really have to create the .dev.vars?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on melops answer above in Typescript:

```js
interface Env {
  var_name: var_type
}

export default {
  async fetch(request: Request, env: Env, context: ExecutionContext): Promise<Response> {
    console.log(env);
  },
};
```

Comment: he is using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Module Workers you should be able to access your secrets via `env`.

```js
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, context) {
      return new Response(`TOKEN: ${env.TOKEN}`)
    }
}
```

I am currently using [wrangler2](https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler2) version 0.0.17

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20509554/tom), my problem was solved by using the .dev.var file and declaring the SECRET KEYS in the Env interface.